# Clear Zero Both Formula and Non Formula Cells

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have two vba Code and i want to combine as single process. Need someone help please.

**1st Code**:

```
Sub DelAllZeros()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next

        Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not frange Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In frange
                If c.Value = 0 Then
                    c.Formula = ClearContents
                End If
            Next c
        End If
        Set frange = Nothing
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**2nd Code:**

```
Sub DelAllZeros1()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Select
        Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder _
                    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next ws

End Sub
```

1st code will clear the "0" from formula cells and seconds code will clear non formula cells.

Comment: so what you want is to clear "0" from all cells (formulas or none-formulas) ? what is your source range, the entire worksheet ?

Comment: I want to clear all Zero values in my entire workbook. If any cells contain zero (formulas or none-formulas) that should be cleared(like blank)

Comment: Ok, try the code in my answer below, let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below (modifications inside the code comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelAllZerosCombined()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, Rng As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ' set range to occupied range in worksheet (save time in loop)
        Set Rng = ws.Range("A1:" & ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In Rng
                If c.Value = 0 Then 
                    ' unmerge "merged" cells
                    If c.MergeCells Then c.UnMerge

                    c.ClearContents
                End If
            Next c
        End If
        Set Rng = Nothing

    Next ws
    ' resume setting
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i am getting run time error with the above code."we cant do this to a merged cell"

Comment: @ayyappankm try now (added a part to check if cells are merged)

Comment: Great Thanks Shai Rado, Its working fine but its changing formating also, i need not to clear my cell formats. Please help to change that condition also.

Comment: @ayyappankm  what formatting ? Background ? Borders ? What exactly ?

Comment: Its removing Borders

Comment: @ayyappankm try now (removed unecessary line)

Comment: Hi Shai Rado Getting Run Time Error "TYPE MISMATCH"

Comment: @ayyappankm at what line ? look at the debug screen

Comment: If c.Value = 0 Or c.Value = "0" Then ' <-- just in case the cell is formatted as text

Comment: Sorry again i am getting run time error (TYPE MISMATCH) in the line   If c.Value = 0 Then

Comment: did you copy my entire code above ? all of it ? with variables declaration ?

Comment: I ran this code a few times, with different scenarios, works fine. Can you share one of your worksheets data ? where you are getting your error (I can't see any reason why it's not working for you)

Comment: not your workbook, but take a screen-shot of a section of your workbook, or copy it contents to your post

Comment: i have added screen shot

Comment: I saw, can't find a reason. Can you save a single worksheet as a seperate file ? and send a link to that file to Dropbox (or something), I'll try to take a look at it

Comment: Now its working fine, i dont know the reason. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will clear the 0s from the used range in a sheet without changing the format.

Updated:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Cells.Replace what:=0, Replacement:="", _
  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
  SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next ws
```

Comment: No its not working, I need to clear the 0s from entire work book whether its having formula or none formula

Comment: I have updated the code to replace 0s in all worksheets in a workbook.

Comment: Hi your code is removing 0s from non formula cell, i need this for both formula and non formula cell. I already having the code (Read my question) but its having 2vba codes. 1 will clear the 0s from non formula another one is to clear from formula cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setting in File > Options > Advanced and untick the "Show zeros ..." setting. This setting is on a per sheet basis, so, to automate it **for the whole workbook**, put this code into the ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object) 
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False 
End Sub
```

Now zeros will not display on any sheet.

Comment: Did you try it? It will hide all zeros when **any** sheet is activated. Click on any sheet. Can you see any zero values?